# MVVM Multiple User Interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, web

I have a WPF project build up nicely in MVVM, with some WCF webservices and now i'm at the point now where i want to add another user interface (either web or mobile).

The Views and ViewModels are currently encapsulated a WPF project. If i wanted to create a new web interface, what would be the best way to leverage the ViewModel logic in the web project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good reason to keep your view models and views in separate projects, with the view project referencing the view model project. As is, you would have to have the web user interface project reference all the WPF code to get the view model code that you want. I don't know how feasible it is for you to refactor the WPF project into two projects, but I'd look into that If I were in your position.